# Databinding subproperty object null

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, data-binding

I have DataGrid with explicitly created columns in code. I am binding WPF element in code like this:

```
var path = "ReferenceProperty." + otherObj.StringProperty;
var dataBinding = new Binding(path) { TargetNullValue = "not set" };
```

The problem occurs when i create new row in the DataGrid, the ReferenceProperty is null and exception is thrown. 
If i try to create ReferencePropertys object in the default ctor NHibernate argues that transient object wasn't saved before flush.
How can i solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to specify a cascade for this many-to-one reference. Either set it to all or save-update.

Comment: But i really don't want to create dump object. I'd like rather somehow to check if ReferenceProperty not null.